# How to debug a C application that is called by another process and ends very quickly in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio-debugging

I can't attach to the C application process because it ends only milliseconds after being called. And the caller is an exe that I don't have the source code.

Comment: Run it directly under debugger? Add sleep?

Comment: Add logging, as most primitive alternative like `fprintf()`s?

Answer (score 0):

It's an annoying method but you can set a bbreakpoint in your sub-program, use CreateProcess (or one of its variants) to start the program with CREATE_SUSPENDED in the dwCreationFlags argument. Next attach to the suspended process, and finally resume the suspended program's main thread using the Debug -> Windows -> Threads window. The breakpont is necessary because otherwise the program will simply run to completion once the thread is resumed.

Or use trace debugging (although if it's not a console program you'll probably need to write to a log file).

Comment: I don't have the source code of the caller and I can't change how it CreateProcess …

Comment: You could also add a call to _CrtDbgBreak() in your called program and then attach to the process when the breakpoint exception is raised.